# Swift - Timer not able to access updated instance property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, react-native

Im my react native project's native module I need to send some data periodically from Objective-C to Swift so I am using NSNotificationCenter. I receive the data successfully in my Swift class, inside the function attached to the observer, and I store it in a property.

If I access this property from any instance method call I can see that the value has updated.

However if I access the same property in the selector function attached to the Timer it appears as if the value has not been updated and I cannot figure out why? It seems as if the timer selector function does not have access to anything except the initial value of the property - I have also tried passing the property as part of userInfo to the Timer but the issue is the same.

```c
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stateDidUpdate" object:nil userInfo:state];
```

```swift
class StateController {

  var state: Dictionary<String, Any> = Dictionary()
  var timer: Timer = Timer()
  
    func subscribeToNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self, selector: #selector(receivedStateUpdate),
        name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "stateDidUpdate"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func receivedStateUpdate(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let state = notification.userInfo {
            self.state = (state as? Dictionary<String, Any>)!
            print("\(self.state)") // I can see that self.state has been updated here
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        self.timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(accessState(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timer.fire()
        RunLoop.current.add(self.timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2))
    }

     @objc func accessState(timer: Timer) {
        print("\(self.state)") // state is an empty Dictionary when accessed here
    }

    func printState() {
        "\(self.state)" // value printed is the updated value received from the notification
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that multiple instances of my Swift class being created was causing the issue. I assumed that React Native would create a singleton when calling a native module but it appears multiple instances are created as I could see how many times the init method was called. Switching to a Singleton pattern resolved the issue for me following this excellent [video](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift) and this excellent [gist](https://gist.github.com/harveyconnor/7b0e778effaae302f512485c18881569) on how to create a singleton in a react native project

```swift
class StateController {
    static let shared = StateController()
    private override init() {
    }

}
```